# Xamarin iOS Symbolicate: Still has generic crash info?

Tags: ios, xamarin, crash

Is there a way we can build our app to show better symbolicated crash reports, or is this the most Xamarin can do with iOS crash reports?

We have an app in testflight for iOS, and we have people sending their crash reports. It crashes consistently on a page so the app is up and running. The below code is when we symbolicate either by using the "Open in Xcode" button in safari or running it via CLI. A guess is our dotnetstandard frameworks we're referencing aren't being included in the .dsym when building and this is why it shows a plcrash.  Or it could be that something else is crashing and this is all the noise after it?

*We might go down the route of VS App Center crash SDK but I found some instances where the app will crash and still not report to App Center.*

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7948b38 __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f0acb3bc pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1668)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018bc4444c __abort + 128 (abort.c:155)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018bbec530 abort + 180 (abort.c:126)
4   OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x000000011165ffd8 xamarin_find_protocol_wrapper_type + 0
5   OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x00000001115263f0 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 220685296 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 219107236
6   OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x00000001114bb54c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 220247372 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 218669312
7   OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x00000001114b9f20 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 220241696 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 218663636
8   OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x00000001114afc9c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 220200092 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 218622032
9   OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x0000000104a6526c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 8082028 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 6503968
10  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x000000010461c8dc plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 3590364 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 2012304
11  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x00000001046241f4 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 3621364 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 2043304
12  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x0000000105991ecc plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 23994060 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 22416000
13  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x00000001049e9d80 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 7576960 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 5998900
14  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x00000001114cd2b8 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 220320440 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 218742380
15  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x0000000111587a0c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 221084172 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 219506112
16  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x000000011158b24c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 221098572 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 219520512
17  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x0000000104435f70 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 1597296 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 19236
18  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x0000000104436a54 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 1600084 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 22024
19  Foundation                      0x0000000182276f00 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 212 (NSThread.m:1058)
20  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180afc414 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1972)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180b0d1a0 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208 (CFRunLoop.c:2016)
22  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180a466f8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 368 (CFRunLoop.c:2061)
23  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180a4c05c __CFRunLoopRun + 828 (CFRunLoop.c:2951)
24  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180a5fbc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
25  GraphicsServices                0x000000019cbcb374 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200)
26  UIKitCore                       0x00000001833d3b58 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100 (UIApplication.m:3511)
27  UIKitCore                       0x0000000183155090 UIApplicationMain + 364 (UIApplication.m:5064)
28  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x0000000105a74dc8 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 24923592 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 23345532
29  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x00000001059c4e90 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 24202896 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 22624836
30  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x000000010447a134 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 1876276 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 298216
31  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x00000001049e9d80 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 7576960 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 5998900
32  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x00000001114cd2b8 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 220320440 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 218742380
33  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x0000000111587a0c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 221084172 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 219506112
34  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x000000011158dcc0 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 221109440 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 219531380
35  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x00000001114ab6a4 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 220182180 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 218604120
36  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x0000000111668874 xamarin_GetFolderPath + 4848
37  OurXamarin.App.iOS              0x000000010447a050 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 1876048 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 297988
38  dyld                            0x0000000112a95da4 start + 520 (dyldMain.cpp:879)
```